# Modelling a transformer

Tags: transformer

Is there a model to describe the behaviour of a [power transformer](https://new.siemens.com/global/en/products/energy/high-voltage/transformers/power-transformers.html)?
Ideally in regard to several physical quantities. Is there something, even something basic?

add-on: I'm not looking for an electric circuit but for a mathematical description how a transformer behaves in dependency on oil temperatures, hot spot temperature, gas analysis, bushing monitoring, voltage loads and currents and what is left.

Comment: Yes. Many. What kind of model are you looking for? What kind of behaviour do you want to see in the model?

Comment: Is this good enough? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/307744/transformer-modelling-and-impedance (bottom one)

Comment: @winny I think this wouldn't apply properly to house-large transformers :p

Comment: @ben what's the difference between a small transformer and a large one?

Comment: @Puffafish Good question, at the moment I'm gathering everything that is available. But in principle it is about to describe the behaviour/q-point of a transformer related to its critical quantities which are oil temperature, bushing monitoring, gas analysis, currents and loads and so on.
Finally, I'm looking for a mathematical description how these quantities enter an equation to result in a scalar(?). I'm definitely not looking for an electronic circuit!

Comment: @Puffafish The size. It also makes a difference if you build a bridge from a table to another or from a mountain to another. Everything changes.

Comment: @Ben OK that could do with being made clear in the question "a model of a power transformer" is pretty simple. A full model could be expressed in a single line of pSpice. Or a simple equation in PLECs. If you want to know how it operates across temperatures etc, that is a lot more complicated and depends on your exact transformer. A model of which you either have to make yourself via experimentation or ask your supplier for.

Comment: @Ben It sure would. That's the beauty of a model. EDIT: Oh, that's a compleatly different question, almost mechanical in nature. Anyway, it's too broad.

Comment: @ben yes, a bridge between tables is different to a bridge between hills. But only in the value of the numbers, not in the physical requirements. It still needs to have a length, take a load etc etc. They will both be effected by temperature, winds and so on, the question is by how much.

Comment: the mechanical influences are rather small but yes, in principle, there are also mechanical quantities the transformer depends on. But the ones I mentioned are afaik the most important ones. However, I would like to know if there is a model to use them so one knows "Transformer is stable/is not stable".

Comment: @Puffafish Sure, and as you said, the external influences would change the system differently. And the most obvious difference: I think a table transformer is not housed in oil :)

Comment: It makes very little electrical differnce if it's immersed in oil or not, the model is the same.

Comment: @Ben They can be. I have known them housed in a resin, and water cooled. And I have known of larger ones sat in the workshop relying on just air to cool them.

Comment: I'm quite sure you need a few more engineers to build a power transformer instead of a computer transformer. You can be sure my assumption is valid ;)

Comment: However, it is not about the difference..  I don't want to describe the transformer electrically but physically!

Comment: @Ben I would suggest asking on the physics stake exchange site then. This is the electrical engineering, so things tend to be done electrically.

Comment: An electric circuit is a mathematical description...

Answer (score 1):

For a power transformer at minimum you would probably want to [simulate saturation](https://hvdc.ca/webhelp/EMTDC/Transformers/The_Classical_Approach/the_classical_approach.htm) (as that is commonly used for saftey in the event of a fault)

A circuit is a graphical mathematical description, if you want the math, you or someone else will need to convert this circuit to a state space description. Spice programs such as LT spice do this automatically.

There are also commercially available physics simulators like comsol, CST or ansys that can do a 3d Finite Element Model (FEM). Or [this](https://www.emworks.com/application/3-phase-cylindrical-transformer)

[image]
Source: https://hvdc.ca/webhelp/EMTDC/Transformers/The_Classical_Approach/the_classical_approach.htm

If you want the physical parameters, you model the circuit, and then figure out how much heat is produced from the components, then size the rest of the system around that.

Comment: Thanks, this seems more for designing a transformer. Or in other words, I cannot really imagine a multi million dollar device, very critical for energy supply, will be modelled through LTSpice?
Comsol seems more capable I would say but nevertheless: Once the transformer is build and running, those simulation tools are not helpfull anymore? Or?

Comment: IMO simulation tools should only be used for *verifying designs* you should be able to use a paper/pencil and/or excel to get the rough cut numbers done, then use a simulation to verify any questions you may have about the design. Then build it.

Comment: and how to proceed when it has already been built and is in the field?

Comment: If you had a 3d solid model you could just simulate it, be aware that most transformer or 3d fem packages run in the 10k$'s for pricing

Comment: but a simulation can't depict real world conditions and influences

Comment: A simulation is only an approximation, and the engineer needs to understand what they are approximating, and when that approximation is sufficient for their purposes. Usually the more detailed a simulation, the more time and money will be spent for 'the detail'

Comment: Sure, but a simulation will still not give you any values in real-time about your real world device. And hence, no monitoring information.

Comment: Not true, in many cases models are used in real time for control, you must have sufficient measurements to effectively communicate what is happening in the real world to the model.